# MySQL Query Result as a specified string if int equals

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL

I have the following query

```
"SELECT Status, COUNT( ticket_id) AS total FROM tickets GROUP BY Status"
```

Which returns

```
Status ¦ Total  
0      ¦   3
2      ¦   1
3      ¦   6
```

Is it possible to change the result to a pharse, for example if

0 = Open, 1 = Hold, 2 = Awaiting End User Response, 3 = Resolved, 4 = Closed.

So then the result of the query would be

```
Status                 ¦ Total  
Open                   ¦   3
Awaiting end user      ¦   1
Resolved               ¦   6
```

Any help would be awesome,
Cheers!

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_elt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `case` expression :

```
select (case (Status) 
               when 0 then 'Open' 
               when 1 then 'Hold'
               when 2 then 'Awaiting End User Response'
               when 3 then 'Resolved'
               when 4 then 'Closed'
        end) as total, count(ticket_id) AS total 
from tickets t
group by (case (Status) 
               when 0 then 'Open' 
               when 1 then 'Hold'
               when 2 then 'Awaiting End User Response'
               when 3 then 'Resolved'
               when 4 then 'Closed'
          end);
```

Comment: As Yogesh stated, you can use a case statement to replace the status integer with the phrase. Alternatively, you could create a table giving the relationship between the code and the description for the status, join to that table, and display the description instead of the code.
The code tables ( Status_Code, Status_Description in this case) are really useful for ease of maintenance.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you for your response.  I moved my commentary.

Comment: @yogeshsharma Thanks for your assisstance it is working exactly as I need. Top Man!